# Using an image in django/python

Tags: python, html, django, image

I want to add an image for every post and I already tried setting the static link:

`<img src="{% static {{ post.img }}">`

I also tried uploading the img by writing in the models.py:

`image = models.ImageField(upload_to=.....)`

But it still does not work.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(default="---")
    img = models.CharField(max_length=125, default='--')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Products.views.post', args=[self.slug])
```

### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response , get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Index.html', {"posts": posts})

def post(request, slug):
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)})
```

Comment: Please add your model class in full to the question so we can see more code and help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that my settings.py wasn't configured correctly to display images so i had to add

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the things you've tried here a small summary:

The `{% static %}` template tag refferes to your static files, which means you should not use a variable in there to display the content. 
Mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static).

Except your Post model has a

```
img = models.CharField(...)
```

with the static file path to your image.

In your second attempt by adding a `ImageField` to your post model you should take the `ImageField`s property by calling `{{ post.img.url }}` as `src` of you `img`-Tag

Comment: It isn't working my html tag is `<img src="{{ post.img.url }}" >` my models.py img variable is `img = models.ImageField(upload_to='temp', default=' ')`

Comment: can you add your view to your question?

Comment: are you trying to render your image in your index, or post view?

Comment: in the index view

Comment: That's a bit different.
Since you got a `QueryDict` of `Posts` you will need to iterate over them by using a for loop. Descriped in the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) as well. ([see this example](https://gist.github.com/philsupertramp/5ace4ad537cc3ed6f4a19a25de6d23e3))
I really recommend you to read the template tags site, it's amazing what django offers you out of the box ;)

Comment: I already tried that and now I went with creating an apache server and hosting the images there and then taking the url as a variable I set when creating the post in the admin panel and doing `<img src="{{ post.img }}>"` and that works perfectly thanks for the help anyways